# How to: specify and implement a fallback locale for intl dateformatting

Tags: flutter, dart

In my app I am using two unsupported languages, Welsh and Somali.

Unfortunately I am getting "Invalid Locale" errors when trying to use DateFormat.

I can see that there is some kind of "fallback" locale that can be implemented, and possibly in the "onFailure" method for intl.verifiedLocale ..

I just can't figure out what I need to do to specify/implement this fallback locale.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Intl Verified Locale
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/Intl/verifiedLocale.html